# How can I disable Wi-Fi on router from terminal?

Tags: command-line, networking, wireless, internet, router

I have a `Ubee DDW3611` router with `Wi-Fi` and main computer connected via cable to this router. I would like to disable / enable the `Wi-Fi` on router in terminal running some script. I have the admin access to the router.

The reason for this, that I do not use `Wi-Fi` while using main computer and I do not want strong `Wi-Fi` signal running in the working room.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: is your router got openwrt firmware on it ?

Comment: This will very much depend on your router.

Comment: I have added exact type of router I have.

Comment: Unless your *WiFi access point* (included in the router) is running Ubuntu, this question is off topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will take some work.

General steps to accomplish this:

1. Turn on `tcpdump` on your computer. Have it listen for the traffic between the computer and the router on port 80.
2. In your browser, turn on the Wi-Fi on the router, or turn it off.
3. Carefully study the traffic as dumped by `tcpdump`. You want to look for URLs retrieved by GET and POST commands, as well as cookies, etc.
4. Recreate the traffic using `curl` commands. You can do practically anything with `curl`.

Put the `curl` commands in a script. You may need to store the output of one `curl` command in a file, then do some `sed`, `awk` and `grep` magic to construct the next `curl` command.

Comment: Without further assistance I am not able to achieve it.

Comment: As I said, it's gonna take some work. It will require you to study the various parameters of `curl` and `tcpdump`, and some dexterity in extracting the right information from what the router sends you. But it is definitely possible. If I had such a router, I would have loved to give it a try.

Comment: Ok, I accept the answer, as it might help other users in the future. Thought the answer is too open and it does not solve my answer.

Comment: That's indeed the perfect way to create a script to turn on/of router features!